# Get seperate process by pid nodejs

Tags: node.js, process, pid

Is there a way to get a process by it's process id in node.js? You have the default `process` object in node, something similar to that object, but i can get an existing process on the system. Something like:`var otherProcess = getProcessById(12345)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [find-process](https://github.com/yibn2008/find-process) library maybe help you

you can find process by `pid`:

```
const find = require('find-process');

find('pid', 12345)
  .then(function (list) {
    console.log(list);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err.stack || err);
  })
```

EDIT:

for communication between `process` you can use `ipc` (inter process communication)
check [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) npm package

Comment: This isn’t really what i was needing. This just allows me to search for processes, not access them. Something that allows me to send to stdin, listen for stdout and stderr, and detect when the process ends. If you want a better idea, think the child_process module’s “spawn” but i can just access a running process.

Comment: you want something like `ipc`? @TKDKid1000

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Didn't see that. Checked your new answer.